# simplify :$\frac{1}{f_5}+\frac{1}{f_6}+\frac{1}{f_{12}}+\frac{1}{f_{20}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> let :
>
> $$f_n=\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[n]{4} \ \ \ n\geq2 \in \mathbb{N}$$
>
> then simplify :
> $$\dfrac{1}{f_5}+\dfrac{1}{f_6}+\dfrac{1}{f_{12}}+\dfrac{1}{f_{20}}=?$$

MyTry :

$$f_5=\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[5]{4} \ \ \ , \  \ f_6=\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[6]{4} \ \ , \ \ f_{20}=\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[20]{4}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[5]{4}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[6]{4}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[12]{4}}+\dfrac{1}{{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[20]{4}}}=?$$

Now :

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[5]{4}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[6]{4}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[6]{4}+\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[5]{4}}{(\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[5]{4})(\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[6]{4})}$$

And :

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[12]{4}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[20]{4}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[20]{4}+\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[12]{4}}{(\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[12]{4})(\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[20]{4})}$$

now what ?

Comment: not much of a try, eh?

Comment: Why would you imagine this can be "simplified"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael. I'm sorry .I edited

Answer (score 4):

You get that $$\frac1{\sqrt[20]{32}+\sqrt[20]{256}}+\frac1{\sqrt[12]{8}+\sqrt[12]{16}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[12]{8}+\sqrt[12]{4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[20]{32}+\sqrt[20]{4}}$$
If we group first and fourth and second and third term we get
$$\frac1{\sqrt[20]{32}(1+\sqrt[20]{8})}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[20]{4}(1+\sqrt[20]{8})}+\frac1{\sqrt[12]{8}(1+\sqrt[12]{2})}+\frac1{\sqrt[12]{4}(1+\sqrt[12]{2})}=\\=\frac{\sqrt[20]{8}+1}{\sqrt[20]{32}(\sqrt[20]{8}+1)}+\frac{\sqrt[12]{2}+1}{\sqrt[12]{8}(\sqrt[12]{2}+1)}\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt[20]{32}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[12]{8}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[4]{2}}=2^{\frac34}$$